# Podman-docker container has not started while executing the run command in linux ( Rhel 8 ) server

Tags: linux, docker, podman, rhel8

While trying to run the podman docker container in Linux server (Rhel 8) facing below issue.

> WARN[0000] error mounting subscriptions, skipping entry in /usr/share/containers/mounts.conf: getting host subscription data: failed to read subscriptions from "/usr/share/rhel/secrets": open /usr/share/rhel/secrets/redhat.repo: permission denied

**Execution command:** `podman run -d --name redis_server -p 6377:6377 redis`

I have followed [these steps](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/running_containers_as_systemd_services_with_podman) to run the container

Could you please suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: I guess `podman login` and login to your RHEL account.

Answer (score 0):

giving reference as this solved my issue quoting answer:

I solved my specific problem. The original user account I was using had an empty mounts.conf file (copy the one in usr/share/containers).

use touch ~/.config/containers/mounts.conf

[1874621 – Rootless Podman Unable to Use Host Subscriptions](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1874621)

Comment: I would consider upvoting the answer, but this answer doesn't explain the solution.  It seems like you are simply overwriting the mounts.conf by creating an empty file.  Looks like a work around which silences the warning but it is not necessarily a correct solution.